# Long Flux sometimes not complete

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My need is to transfer some item from a not reactive repository to a reactive repository(Firestore).
The procedure is triggered from a REST endpoint exposed with Netty.
The code below is what I've written after some trial and errors.

The query from the non reactive repo is not long (~20sec) but it returns a lot of records and the execution time is usually ~60min.

All records are always saved, all "Saving in progress... XXX" are printed, but about 50% if the times, it will not print "Saved XXX records" and no errors are printed.

Things I've noticed:

- more records -> higher probability of fails
- it does not depends on the execution time (sometimes longer process than the failed ones completes)

The app runs on a k8s pod with 1500Mi RAM request and 3000Mi limit, from the graphs it never approaches the limit.

What I'm missing here?

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/import")
public class ImportController {

    @Autowired
    private NotReactiveRepository notReactiveRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ReactiveRepository reactiveRepository;

    private static final Scheduler queryScheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(1, 480, "query", 864000);// max 10 days processing time

    @GetMapping("/start")
    public Mono<String> start() {
        log.info("Start");
        return Mono.just("RECEIVED")
                //fire and forget
                .doOnNext(stringRouteResponse -> startProcess().subscribe());
    }

    private Mono<Long> startProcess() {
        Mono<List<Items>> resultsBlockingMono = Mono
                .fromCallable(() -> notReactiveRepository.findAll())
                .subscribeOn(queryScheduler)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(5, Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)));
        return resultsBlockingMono
                .doOnNext( records -> log.info("Records: {}", records.size()))
                .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
                .map(ItemConverter::convert)
                // max 9000 save/sec
                .delayElements(Duration.of(300, ChronoUnit.MICROS))
                .flatMap(this::saveConvertedItem)
                .zipWith(Flux.range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                .doOnNext(savedAndIndex -> log.info("Saving in progress... {}", savedAndIndex.getT2()))
                .count()
                .doOnNext( numberOfSaved -> log.info("Saved {} records", numberOfSaved));
    }

    private Mono<ConvertedItem> saveConvertedItem(ConvertedItem convertedItem) {
        return reactiveRepository.save(convertedItem)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(1000, Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                    log.error("Resuming");
                    return Mono.empty();
                })
                .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error on save"));
    }
}
```

Update:
As requested, this is the last output of the procedure, where should be "Saved 1131113 records" and with `.log()` before `.count()` (the output after the onNext always prints after the process, also on success):

```
"Saving... 1131113"
"| onNext([ConvertedItem(...),1131113])"
"Shutting down ExecutorService 'pubsubPublisherThreadPool'"
"Shutting down ExecutorService 'pubSubAcknowledgementExecutor'"
"Shutting down ExecutorService 'pubsubSubscriberThreadPool'"
"Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'"
"HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated..."
"HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed."
```

Comment: is there any special reason as to why you are running the entire request on a scheduler with 1 single thread allocated? because no wonder its going slow if it only has one single thread to work with. And also, you should not be `subscribing` the calling client is the subscriber, your application is the producer, do `return startProcess().thenReturn("RECEIVED");`

Comment: The single thread for the query is for not to overload the production db, the single thread on the writes is to have more control on how many records/sec we write (firestore supports max 10k write/sec). The speed is not a priority for this process, it's fine even if it needs 20 hours, but it needs to complete for the output.
I'm subscribing because I applied the "fire and forget" pattern, the user will receive the "RECEIVED" reply immediately, then the app will continue to work, like a background process.

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm guessing from what you decribe that the count does not receive a termination signal (either error/success). why exactly I have no clue though.. I would suggest to add a .log() before the .count() and have a look at the requests going up and signals going down the chain.

Comment: Do you try to log all events in subscriber? It cannot stop working without any event.

Comment: I'm trying with `.log()` before the `.count()` as @p.streef suggested. Meanwhile I've tryed replacing `.count()` with `.map(Tuple2::getT1).collectList().map(List::size)` and `.map(objects -> 1).reduce(0,Integer::sum)` both with the same result, randomically will not complete. Could it be some time/size limit of flux schedulers?

Comment: edited question with the console output of `.log()`

Comment: Can you use log in subscriber instead `log()` operator?

Comment: @Mister_Jesus changed `startProcess().subscribe()` to `startProcess().subscribe( longOut -> log.info("Subscriber: {}", longOut ), throwable -> log.error("Subscriber error", throwable), () -> log.info("Subscriber complete") )` but nothing more than the previous test is printed on the logs

Comment: Not a solution, but I've switched from Firestore to PostgreSQL and 
there are no more problems. Maybe there is a bug on the Firestore driver.